# Spring MVC - collection of string

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo, spring-webflow

I want to have an entity with a collection of string values, its to store receipt numbers which can be alpha-numeric, hence the need to store strings. How do I add such a field to an entity with spring roo?

I tried

`field set --fieldName controlNumbers --type java.lang.String --class ~.model.Receipt` 
but that produced an error about the specified type cannot be found in the project, i need to create it first.

I then tried to directly inject the code below into the entity and save it and that updated the aj files. However that also had problems when I run tomcat.

```
   private Set<String> controlNumbers = new HashSet<String>();
```

Also saw someone do this

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements
private Set<String> controlNumbers = new HashSet<String>();
```

but geuss what, CollectionOfElements is deprecated.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to implement something similar although I wasn't using spring roo but my entity needed to store a Map and the following in my entity did the trick:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "CONFIG_KEY")
@Column(name = "CONFIG_VALUE")
@CollectionTable(name = "CONFIG_MAPPING")
private Map<String, String> configAttributes;
```

Not sure if this will help at all but thought I'd share

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't specify --class

If you want your entity's controlNumbers field to be a collection of strings, don't specify the --class as Receipt, just leave the --type as java.lang.String.  If you want it to be a collection of Receipts, then don't specify java.lang.String.

Also, your Receipt entity must already exist for this to work.  You can't refer to a type that doesn't exist yet.

Once your ~.model.Receipt object exists, you should be able to run:

field set --fieldName controlNumbers --type  ~.model.Receipt

Refer to http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#command-index-field-set
for further examples.

Comment: I tried both, without specifying the class, how does roo know where to put the field? That produced     "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to convert '*' to type JavaType for opti
on 'class'
Unknown type; please indicate the type as a command option (ie --xxxx)". I tried field set --fieldName controlNumbers --type java.lang.String without the "--class" and that produced errors too

Comment: If your ~.model.Receipt exists, 

field set --fieldName receipts --type ~.model.Receipt 

Is all you need

Create a receipt jpa entity then run your field set.

Comment: Or create a controlnumbers jpa entity and have your set refer to that